# Dell R610, Perc 6/i SSD SATA drive slow speed

Tags: dell, ssd, dell-perc

Before buying an SSD for the server I've tried to use SSD from my notebook:

SSD disk (TRANSCEND 2.5" SSD370S 128 gb SATA III MLC TS128GSSD370S) has speed at my notebook 350-400 MB/s.

I installed it to the Perc 6/i of R610. No any other disks in the bay.

All the server's firmware is up to date for 100% (bios 6.5.0, etc).

Configured RAID-0. Installed the system (i tried Windows, Linux, ESXI). Everywhere the speed is 100 MB/s at the start of copying and get slower down to 60 MB/s during the process. While when I used to have 4xSAS 15k in RAID-10 the speed was 150-180 MB/s.

Of course, maybe it is because this SSD is not Dell-approved, but maybe there are some tweaks I could make to speed it up?

And by the way, could you tell me please, where can I find actual info with dell-approved SSD-s?
For example, will a Intel SSD 545s Series SATA 512gb have a 250 MB/s speed at least? Or maybe SSD Intel DC S3520 fits?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A R610 is almost 9 year old+, please contact Dell or a Dell reseller to know which SSD is compatible.

Please note for old gear Dell might no longer have them, and if they still have some for warrenty call, they don’t touch their warrenty stuff for selling to a customer outside warrenty.

I would suggest to get a newer controller in the server to handle the SSD, seem to me a better path in your case.

Comment: But I read that at http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/server-poweredge-r610-tech-guidebook.pdf 
"SSDs require the PERC 6/i or PERC H700 integrated storage controller card and cannot be mixed with any other type of hard drive". 
So maybe the problem in the SSD.

Comment: @Vlad yeah, but try to find that old ssd that work with it, better use a new card, the perc6i is badly rated for ssd

Answer (score 0):

What are you testing? Read speeds? Write speeds? Both?

I agree with yagmoth555 - this controller is from when enterprise SSD support was in its infancy, and I fully expect you would see poor performance like this. You may see some improvement in switching to a PERC H700 controller, but nothing like the improvement you'd see in moving to a more modern card/platform.

With that said, you may want to verify that you have caching tuned for performance by enabling write-back cache and adaptive read-ahead - this may at least make things more tolerable.